# Disminuir tamaño modal bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Utilizando el framework bootstrap, quiero un modal de 730px en width, pero bootstrap no tuliza ésta medida.

```
<div id="modal-apartado" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="title-apartado">
                        <span>¡Este hotel ofrece sistema de apartado!</span>
                    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Intenté cambiar el width en mi hoja de estilos de ésta forma

.modal-dialog {
    width: 730px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

peroooo, de ésta forma, se pierde la funcionalidad responsiva.

Existe una forma de cambiar el width pero que mantengan la función responsiva?

Comment: intentaste usar `max-width`?

Comment: :O no lo habia pensado

Comment: o sobre escribir la propiedad `@media` para que solo aplicara  las modificaciones `.modal-dialog` en pantallas grandes?

Comment: noo, es necesario?

Comment: No, pero es otra manera en la que lo puedes hacer. Te recomiendo leer la entrada de [W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: ok, gracias, lo voy a leer